# World War 2 movie about a female artist and a Nazi officer

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remembered a little about this movie, I think it's set in World War 2. As I remember in the movie a woman that's good in painting makes a Nazi officer fall in love with her.

The officer always wants to be painted and he takes her to his room as a love partner. Nobody can't touch the girl in his room other than him because he is a high rank until one time something happens. When he was out of the quarters an officer reported that he captured a woman there and one officer raped her. Then he knew who raped her and when they were in patrol with the officer that raped his girl he killed that officer. At that time his high rank father came to see the woman and asked some question and then asked to paint him the woman did and been spare by painting...(this movie has nudity and rape).

As for the ending I think when she's out in quarters she speaks with some allies about where they are camping (the Nazi that loves her). It's in a church and the allies bomb it and the Nazi survived and knew that the woman is a traitor and I think he killed her in the end (not quite sure about the ending).

I think its German with English sub and I think the movie was around 2009-2013 when it was released? Not quite sure? As I remember the title of the movie was in German? Or name of the girl?

Comment: What language was the movie in? And what year did you watch it?

Comment: I think its german with english sub and i thinks the movie was around 2009-2013 when its relaease? Not quite sure?as i remember the title of the movie was in german? Or name of the girl?

Answer (score 2):

The movie is ["In the Land of Blood and Honey"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1714209/), American war drama film from 2011, written, produced, and directed by Angelina Jolie.

The movie takes place during the war in Bosnia and telling the story about Danijel (Serbian soldier), and Ajla (Bosniak artist).

> Danijel and Ajla feel a spark of love at a carefree dance on the last night of peace. The bomb that rips through a nightclub defines them as enemies, and not long after that, Danijel saves Ajla from certain rape and arranges for her special treatment in a prison. She gets her own sunny room, and in this privacy, they luxuriate in love in the afternoon.
>
> Danijel's brainstorm is to appoint Ajla the "official artist" of the Serbian army and set her to work painting the portraits of Serbian generals.

[image: Ajla and Danijel]

> Danijel’s father, a famous general named Nebojsa Vukojevic, learns that his son is keeping Muslim woman in a room at yet another camp. Nebojsa arrives in her room and demands that she paint him.
>
> When he leaves he sends in a soldier to rape Ajla. Danijel arrives back at the barracks and sees the soldier coming from the direction of his room. He rushes into the room and demands to know from Ajla what that man did to her. After Danijel sees the outline of his father's face on her canvas, he rushes out of the room and goes to talk to the rapist. He gets the rapist to answering many questions and then he shoots him in the head.
>
> Ajla gives in information about Danijel to her people and they organized the bombing of the church in which the Serbs were met. However, Daniele survives the attack, realizing that he was betrayed by Ajla. He kills her and then turns himself in as a criminal to the internationals.